# jQuery, Ajax return nothing Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

My application is throwing a `JSON.parse error` because `Spring MVC` is returning a view which the `XMLHttpRequest` is picking up.

```
 $("#formId").submit(function( event ){
        //var data = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeObject());
        var data = JSON.stringify({"dateSmoked":"26/05/2015 19:00", "excessiveness":10, "intakeMethod":"bong", "comments":"ping"});
        alert(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Client created!! :-)')
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('An error has occured!! :-(');
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        })
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

The code above sends a POST request to the following Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, headers="Content-Type=application/json")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public String createSmokeEvent(@RequestBody SmokeEvent evt)
{
    Account account = (Account) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    System.out.println("Added");
    return "redirect:/users/"+account.getUsername();
}
```

and the controller returns a view - `"redirect:/users/"+account.getUsername()"`. The `XMLHttpRequest` that I am sending seems to be attempting to try and parse the response from the server which is html from the server being returned.

I basically want the application to send the POST request to the server, and let the server handle everything, that is redirecting to the page. No response involved. I don't want jQuery to attempt to parse whatever the controller returns.

Currently, the code always fails as it is attempting to `JSON.parse` a HTML response.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you actually want the browser to be redirected too?

Comment: changing it to 'html' has solved the error. It successfully passes now but it won't redirect the page.

Comment: AJAX generally doesn't result in a redirect to a new page in your browser. You'd either need to not use AJAX or return the URL to redirect to, and redirect in the browser via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your requirement. Basically your controller should return a valid JSON string:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, headers="Content-Type=application/json")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ResponseBody
public Map createSmokeEvent(@RequestBody SmokeEvent evt)
{
    Account account = (Account) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    System.out.println("Added");
    Map m = new LinkedHashMap();
    m.put("result", "ok");
    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Spring, but I'm pretty familiar with jQuery and making AJAX calls with it. It's attempting to parse the response from the AJAX call as JSON because you've told it to (with this option):

```
dataType: 'json',
```

If you're not going to be returning JSON from your server in response to the request, don't tell jQuery to expect JSON and it won't attempt to parse it as such. You can either specify the correct dataType to match the response (probably 'html' based on your description of the problem) or not specify `dataType` at all and let jQuery guess at how it should handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Datatype in ajax must be json,

```
 dataType: 'json'
```

Then use this below ajax success,

```
success: function(response) {
    if (response.redirect) {
        // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
        window.location.href = data.redirect;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public @ResponseBody String createSmokeEvent(@RequestBody SmokeEvent evt) {
   Account account = (Account) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
   System.out.println("Added");
   return "redirect:/users/"+account.getUsername();
}
```

Comment: it successfully passes but its not redirecting the page by using Spring MVC

Comment: okay, try changing dataType: 'json'. Then,  success: function (response) {
               if (response.redirect) {
                window.location.href = response.redirect;
            }
            },

Comment: Not sure why your suggesting json this time round. I just tried it your above solution to 'html'. Its not redirecting :(

Comment: Your editted suggestion isn't throwing an error, but its not redirecting to the page that I've instructed it to using the controller.

Comment: I think your controller return type is not json type. I have added the controller part. Follow that as well.